# Can't add canvas from html2canvas to jspdf addHTML() method

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2canvas

Im building app on top of **angular5** and Im trying to add a html using `jspdf.addHTML()` function combining **html2canvas**.

```
const content = this.vc_print_section.nativeElement;

html2canvas(content).then(canvas => {
   const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');

   doc.addHTML(canvas, _ => {
      doc.save('test.pdf');
   });
});
```

But an error occurred:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object String]
```

Answer (score 1):

jsPDF calls html2canvas by itself in addHTML method. Correct code would have been this one :

```
const content = this.vc_print_section.nativeElement;
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');

doc.addHTML(canvas, _ => {
    doc.save('test.pdf');
});
```

Even this way, if you are using the last version of html2canvas, I think it's not compatible with jsPDF. It may needs some changes in the addhtml.js plugin.